# Is there a way to "Switch row/column" data in a chart?

Tags: python, python-pptx

I am creating a chart and want to switch the rows and columns of the data that I have input before opening the chart in PowerPoint. The series gets formatted and grouped incorrectly and the chart means nothing in this way.

I am using tuples which I understand are hard to manipulate, so if there is a command that I am missing to simply switch the rows/columns? That seems it would be the easiest solution.

```
x3 = Inches(0.3)
y3 = Inches(3.7)
cx3 = Inches(1.25)
cy3 = Inches(1.25)

chart_data_marriage = CategoryChartData()
chart_data_marriage.categories = ['Married HH', 'Married Footprint']

demographics['Profile List Title'] = demographics['Profile List Title'].str.strip()

tuple_married1 = demographics['Family Renters : Users/100 HHs']
tuple_married_footprint = demographics['Profile List: Total Profile Users/100 HHs']


tuple_married1.drop([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,38,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95], inplace = True)

tuple_married_footprint.drop([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,38,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95], inplace = True)

chart_data_marriage.add_series('Family Renters : Users/100 HHs', (tuple_married1))
chart_data_marriage.add_series('Profile List: Total Profile Users/100 HHs', (tuple_married_footprint))

marriagechart = storyboard1.shapes.add_chart(XL_CHART_TYPE.DOUGHNUT, x3, y3, cx3, cy3, chart_data_marriage).chart
marriagechart.has_legend = False
```

Within both `tuple_married1` and `tuple_married_footprint` I have the data that I need to create the doughnut chart, so it is just a matter of formatting the series in the correct order. Again, a switch rows and columns command like the button that exists in PowerPoint right now would be ideal, otherwise a more complex solution might be necessary.

Comment: What sort of object is `demographics`?

Comment: Demographics is a dataframe created by Pandas; I had to parce out the specific data (marriage data) that I needed from the df in the tuples, which is what the .drop([]) command is doing.

Comment: I think you can pass a `range` object to `drop`, e.g. `tuple_married1.drop(range(2,96), inplace = True)`. If not, you can do `tuple_married1.drop(list(range(2,96)), inplace = True)`. Or when you first define `tuple_married1 = demographics['Family Renters : Users/100 HHs']`, put in a row slice. E.g. `tuple_married1 = demographics.loc[rows_i_want,'Family Renters : Users/100 HHs']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`python-pptx` has no "pivot-chart-data" behavior, but it's simple enough to accomplish and kind of an interesting puzzle.

Something like this should do the trick if you plug in your values in the right form (pretty much the same form as you feed to ChartData), and you can of course tweak it to suit:

```
original_cats = ("a", "b", "c")
original_sers = (
    ("Series 1", (1, 2, 3)),
    ("Series 2", (4, 5, 6)),
)

new_cats = tuple(ser[0] for ser in original_sers)
# --> ("Series 1", "Series 2")

new_sers = tuple(
    (original_cats[i], (s[1][i] for s in original_sers))
    for i in range(len(original_cats))
)
# --> (("a", (1, 4)), ("b", (2, 5)), ("c", (3, 6)))
```

Comment: Once I've created new_sers and new_cats, how do I integrade them into the marriagechart? Also, I put your recommended code in after tweaking and I got a KeyError: 0; this might simply be a result of new_cats and new_sers not being used in marriagechart? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Briefly, you would create a new ChartData object, add new_cats and new_sers to it, and then call `chart.replace_data(new_chart_data)` on it.

Answer (score 2):

If your data is coming from a Pandas dataframe, you can do `demographics.T` before you move the data over to `pptx`.